# How can I download examples from Sencha Ext Js?

Tags: extjs

I want to download the examples from sencha ext js: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/, but I havent found a way to it. I gave the 30days free trial, and I really really need the source code. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 2):

Download the framework as zip file (for example gpl version) and there wil be a folder called examples.

Here a screenshot of the 7.0.0 gpl version:

[image]

I guess there will be no big change between 7.0.0 and 7.3.x.

---

Another option just debug the examples using dev tools:

- open iframe
- pretty print via browser console

[image]

Comment: Ok Ive already download the example, do you know how to build it?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried to use a webserver and serve the examples folder?

Answer (score 0):

here are very easy steps to make exactly what you need: [Build Ext JS Admin Dashboard Using Template - GPL Version](https://www.sencha.com/blog/quickly-build-powerful-executive-and-admin-dashboards-with-javascript/)

Basically, you can download GPL version here: https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/

And create your application based on admin template, like this:

```
sencha -sd /Users/fabio/sencha-sdks/ext-7.0.0-gpl generate app -s /Users/fabio/sencha-sdks/ext-7.0.0-gpl/templates/admin-dashboard AdminDashboard ./admin-dashboard-extjs
```

Then you can build it using:

```
sencha app build
```